# How to circular shift numpy array without O(n) memory copying?

Tags: python, numpy, queue, fifo, deque

Short version:

how to do this without O(n) memory copying

```py
    start  = 2            # \/ start points here 
    input  = np.array([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])
    output = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) # output doesn't need to be memory contiguous, a view is just fine
```

Long version:

I'm trying to implement a fixed length FIFO buffer based on numpy.ndarray for hardware simulation.
My goal is to achieve O(1) (or at least less than O(n)) of enqueue/dequeue, and most important: **get numpy array with correct order**.

I end up using a pointer `start` to point at first element of FIFO, thus enqueue/dequeue is just single assignment/indexing which is fast.
But the problem is when I want use this whole FIFO as a numpy.ndarray and do some math(like np.dot(signal,fifo)), I cannot find a way to get corresponding array without an O(n) operation.

It sounds like a wheel that already be invented so I searched online and tried something, but none of these suits my need:

- `input[1:] = input[:-1]; input[0] = new_val` a naive but most efficient way so far, but still O(n)
- collection.deque: good enqueue/dequeue performance, but take long time to work with other numpy array (seems numpy will convert deque to numpy.ndarray first then do the math, which will take a lot of time)
- indexing: `input[np.arange(start,start+size)%size]` this is advanced indexing so it returns new array, and the index array creation part makes it even slower
- `np.r_[input[start:],input[:start]]`, better than indexing when buffer size is large, but still O(n)
- `np.roll(input,-start)`, O(n) and slower
- `np.concatenate([input[start:],input[:start]])`, O(n), slower than naive way but faster than others

since the original array is contiguous so I also tried use strides/shape trick to create a view of original array but not work neither.

So I came here for help, or it has to be O(n)?

Comment: I think subclassing a numpy array would be a slightly tedious but straightforward solution here. I don't know of any existing implementation though.

Comment: @senderle  I tried, but the core problem is still there: get correct-order array from underlying stored memory

Comment: Lok at the code fo `roll` and `r_`.  They uae `concatenate`..  Make a large array, and use a slice to get a sliding view.  When you run out of space, copy the window to a new 'blank' array.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't understood what you mean by "get correct-order array." I like @hpaulj's idea, but I had been imagining that you would override `__getitem__`, etc. to use modular arithmetic. Unless I am mistaken, views would be of the same subclass, and so would use the same overridden `__getitem__` — so like other views, they would be O(1) as desired. Other operations would necessarily be O(n) — copying, `dot`, and so on are all O(n) anyway.

Comment: use space exchange for time is a good idea, but I'm not sure if I will have enough resouce (code will run on some embedded chip).  @senderle And what I mean about 'correct order' is: in memory I have an array `[4,5,1,2,3]`, and a pointer `start=2`, I want a numpy's view or similiar thing that give me `[1,2,3,4,5]` without O(n) memory operation.

Comment: A view of a ndarray subclass is an instance of that subclass, so there's no O(n) operation on view creation. You would just use the same buffer and your overridden `__getitem__` does the rest. So — you already have what you want. The only difference between what I'm proposing and what you're asking for is effectively that `output = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` would become `output = MyNdarraySubclass([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`. But that's as expected in general. Operations on `MyNdarraySubclass` should return instances of `MyNdarraySubclass` and so on.

Comment: Looking over the docs I am reminded that you might also need to re-implement a lot of ufuncs by hand to get full numpy speed. But you could do it. (I did say it would be tedious!)